# Array Sum with Pointers i have a problem in the sum

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, sum

I have this code. and I have a problem with it. When I run it for these numbers `"1,1,1,1,1"` it answers me right but when I use these numbers `"2,1,3,2,2"` or any other numbers it answers me wrong. What is the problem?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int size = 5;
    int array1[size];
    int i, j, *p;

    int sum = 0;
    p = &array1[j];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << "give next number";
        cin >> array1[i];
        cout << "\n";
    }

    cout << "the array is:"
         << "\n";
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        cout << array1[j] << "\n";
        sum = sum + *p;
    }
    cout << "the sum of array elements is: " << sum;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `p=&array1[j];` is nonsense when `j` has no determinate value. Nor does it magically fixup when you change the value of `j` later (which you're not even doing, since the `for(int j...` loop declares its own local `j` anyway).

Comment: how do i fix it then? How is the right code for this..i am new at this so i dont know much

Comment: `size` should be const to prevent a variable length array. And drop the pointer altogether. Just use normal array indexing.

Comment: u helped me a lot.thank u!

Comment: I will! I will study the code and i will try to made a new one with a difference this time. I appreciate all the answers i get and i respect u all. I am a self learner from the internet i do study this because i want to have a mini expirience with this kind of programming. SO i will NOt copy ur answer. Thank u a lot! If i come against an error i will post again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have one problem

```
p = &array1[j];
```

What you are doing is taking the address of `j`th element of an array. In you case `j` is uninitialized which leads to UB since `j` might contain any variable.

To fix this you can initialize `j` to `0` (`j = 0`). Or to just get an address of first element in array you can do following:

```
p = array;
```

Than comes your loop, which is summit value at address of `arr[j]` which is UB as I stated above.

```
cout << "the array is:" << "\n";
for (j = 0; j < size; j++) {
    cout << array1[j] << "\n";
    sum = sum + *(p + j);
}
```

Your problem here was that you were adding `array1[0]` all the time. (That is if you initialized `j` to `0`).

Other things to note is that you are re declaring `i` and `j`

```
int i, j, *p;
...
for (int i = 0; ...)
...
for (int j = 0; ...)
```

You could do just

```
for (i = 0; ...)
...
for (j = 0; ...)
```

to set already declared variables to `0`.

Here is entire program:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int size = 5;
    int array1[size];
    int i, j, *p; 

    int sum = 0;
    // p = &array1[j]; // UB j not initialized but used

    /* solution 1
    j = 0;
    p = &array1[j]
    */
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    // solution 2 which is same as solution 1
    p = array1; // gets address of array[0]
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {    // no need for `int` in front of i
                                    // i is already declared above
                                    // my preference is to declare i here
                                    // and remove declaration above
        std::cout << "give next number";
        std::cin >> array1[i];
        std::cout << "\n";
    }   

    std::cout << "the array is:"
        << "\n";
    for (j = 0; j < size; j++) { // same as above
        std::cout << array1[j] << "\n";
        sum = sum + *(p + j); 
    }   
    std::cout << "the sum of array elements is: " << sum;

    return 0;
}
```

input:

```
give next number5

give next number4

give next number3

give next number2

give next number1
```

output

```
the array is:
5
4
3
2
1
the sum of array elements is: 15
```

Comment: First of all thank u for answering , but i am a begginer in c++ so i would really appreciated if u could show me on a photo or copy-paste my programme and do the changes so i can run it and understand it better?           because i lost u after change j=0

Comment: u have miss understand me. I did not trick anyone the code in my question is my code i made it and i do not have a homework for school or something i just studying for myself from the internet for more experience and i am a girl.

Comment: I will study the code and i will try to made a new one with a difference this time. I appreciate all the answers i get and i respect u all. So please don't judge me by my question. Thank u a lot!